# Should ATI catalyst be installed for sake of openCL?

Tags: ati, hybrid-graphics, opencl

I have a HP Envy 4 1025tx with Hybrid graphics. Although this is a 64bit system, I've installed 32bit Ubuntu on it for some reasons.(Hybrid graphics don't do well with 64bit Ubuntu.-"Some one on some forum")

I had heating problems with the GPU but I've fixed them all with vgaswitcheroo. But now I wanted to use my Blender on my Ubuntu. To my surprise Blender didn't detect the dedicated 7670m card in my machine. I've confirmed with

```
cat /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch
```

Both IGD and DIS were up and running. I dont seem to have libopencl on my /usr/lib even though my synaptic manager says that I have installed it. I'm not quite sure what I've installed. It says that I've installed "ocl-icd-libopencl1".

So my question is...

> Do I have opencl on my system?
>
> If not do I have to get propreitary ATI drivers for sake of opencl(fglrx wrecks up my unity totally on my system I need directions to fix it if this is the choice)?
>
> Should I get a 64bit Ubuntu installed on this system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**FIXED IT**

After many rigorous torture tests, finally I could get the GPU boost + Powersaving CPU modes and all that was available on Windows. ATI's fglrx will work with Linux mint maya-64bit better than with Ubuntu. I just had to download the drivers from mint's additional hardware drivers section. It was not at all difficult.

Must note. Once you get these drivers, you might have to live a geek's life for the rest of the time. Cinnamon launches perfectly flawless with GPU on but on performance mode it doesn't even launch. In order to launch it you need to stop the mdm service and relaunch it then you have to launch cinnamon as a sudo.

But finally I got proper drivers for my system :D